# Python binary search finding all non-duplicate numbers

Tags: python, algorithm

I've been trying to write a binary search function to find all unique numbers in a list. I know that I have to find the middle value of a list and compare it with the first and last element depending on the size of the number. But I can't see how all elements are checked against each other to find non-duplicates.
I could easily do len(set(list)) to remove all duplicates, but not sure how to use it in binary search.

Would appreciate your help.

Comment: Please include your current code.

Comment: Binary search of a list only works if the list is sorted, and it really only makes sense if you're looking for a single value.  If you have a sorted list and you want to dedupe it, you want to just traverse it in a straight line, not binary-search for each element.  Maybe you could clarify more about the list and why you specifically are trying to use binary search for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite possible to achieve that if the list is in sorted order first. This is how it should work:  (*quote from various web sources)*
This example shown here is just try to find single duplicated number.

It can be done in O(Log n) time. The observation is here:

All numbers before the required have the first occurrence at even index (0, 2, ..) and next occurrence at odd index (1, 3, …). And all elements after the required elements have the first occurrence at odd index and next occurrence at even index.

1. Find the middle index, say ‘mid’.
2. If ‘mid’ is even, then compare A[mid] and A[mid + 1]. If both are the same, then the required element after ‘mid’ else before mid.
3. If ‘mid’ is odd, then compare A[mid] and A[mid – 1]. If both are the same, then the required element after ‘mid’ else before mid.

Let's have some code snippet to demo the idea/steps:

```py
    def binary_search(A, l, h):
        # l: low, h: high  <- Base case
        if l > h: return None
        if l == h: return A[l]
    
        # the middle point
        mid = (h + l)//2
    
        # If mid is even ...
        if mid % 2 == 0:
            if A[mid] == A[mid+1]:
                return binary_search(A, mid+2, h)
            else:
                return binary_search(A, l, mid)
        else:
            if A[mid] == A[mid-1]:    # mid is odd
                return binary_search(A, mid+1, h)
            else:
                return binary_search(A, l, mid-1)
    
    # Test code
    A = [1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]
    
    single = binary_search(A, 0, len(A)-1)
    
    print(f'The unique number is {single} ')
```

```
 Output:
        3
```

Comment: What if you have three 1s? This is a clever approach only if numbers are duplicated exactly twice, but without knowing more, it's hard to say if this is a valid answer.

Comment: Good point.  @Mad Physicist - then the case should be modified.  The code/explanation is just to answer how the binary search can work for the case.  I believe the post has done that.  Right?

Comment: Please see @Samwise earlier comments about finding multiple unique numbers.

Comment: @Daniel Hao. Thank you very much for the answer. This made it very clear.

Comment: @iOSEnthusiast if this help you, please upvote and select it's acceptance.  Thx

Comment: @Daniel Hao. Accepted, but can't upvote, due to lower than 15 reputation.